# Netty Error with ssl certificate on android

Tags: java, android, ssl, libgdx, netty

I'm having trouble with netty on android (on pc everything works). I'm using securechat example [link](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat) and on this line:

```
SelfSignedCertificate ssl = new SelfSignedCertificate();
```

i'm getting that error

```
    07-31 13:01:39.861: W/System.err(8693): java.security.cert.CertificateException: No provider succeeded to generate a self-signed certificate. See debug log for the root cause.
07-31 13:01:39.861: W/System.err(8693):     at io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate.<init>(SelfSignedCertificate.java:115)
07-31 13:01:39.861: W/System.err(8693):     at io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate.<init>(SelfSignedCertificate.java:82)
07-31 13:01:39.861: W/System.err(8693):     at io.netty.handler.ssl.util.SelfSignedCertificate.<init>(SelfSignedCertificate.java:71)
```

Everything works earlier and now not and i don't know why. I'm running server in thread.